# How can you force Mercurial (hg) to treat a file as binary?

Tags: text, mercurial, binary, hgserve

I have a LaTeX hg repository for a paper and I use `hg serve` to display the progress to my coauthors.
Until last week the file paper.pdf was treated as binary and its contents were not displayed in the changesets. (The users could download it via the `raw` link)

Since last week, paper.pdf is treated as text and I see huge diffs of PDF code in my changesets...

Is there a way to tell the repository to treat this file as binary instead of "guessing" ?

On my server (where hg serve runs):
hg --version  --> Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 1.0.1)
on my laptop:
hg --version  --> Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 1.3.1)

Comment: Martin's comment on Tonfa's comment is the key -- mercurial doesn't differentiate between text and binary in any way that affects functionality at all.  It'll show up different in user facing diffs (and depending on your --git setting), but under the covers it's all binary and there's never any line-ending conversion dataloss like svn and cvs could yield.

Answer (score 2):

You can't override the heuristic (which is quite simple, it just checks for the presence of a NUL byte in the data).

I guess the generated PDF isn't compressed which means it is just plain text, and it doesn't contain any NUL byte.

But why is it important for you to have it as binary?

Comment: Let me just add, that regardless of what `hg diff` shows you, Mercurial will use a binary diff format internally.

Comment: I am looking into ways to get a NULL byte somewhere
in the PDF file...

I tried this:  
   \usepackage[pdftex]{graphics}
   \pdfcompresslevel=9

but it seems I wasn't lucky enough to get a NULL in the pdf.
I will add some more high-res pictures ;)
And one day when I submit I will look at the `hg serve` source code...